# Sum Distinct Rows Only In Sql Server

Tags: sql

I have four tables,in which `First` has one to many relation with rest of three tables named as (`Second`,`Third`,`Fourth`) respectively.I want to sum only Distinct Rows returned by select query.Here is my query, which i try so far.

```
select count(distinct First.Order_id) as [No.Of Orders],sum( First.Amount) as [Amount] from First 
inner join Second  on First.Order_id=Second.Order_id
inner  join Third  on Third.Order_id=Second.Order_id
inner  join  Fourth  on Fourth.Order_id=Third.Order_id
```

The outcome of this query is :

```
No.Of Orders                       Amount
7                                  69
```

But this `Amount` should be **49**,because the sum of First column `Amount` is **49**,but due to inner join and one to many relationship,it calculate sum of also duplicate rows.How to avoid this.Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is cartesian products in the joins (for a given id).  You can solve this using `row_number()`:

```
select count(t1234.Order_id) as [No.Of Orders], sum(t1234.Amount) as [Amount]
from (select First.*,
             row_number() over (partition by First.Order_id order by First.Order_id) as seqnum
      from First inner join
           Second
           on First.Order_id=Second.Order_id inner join
           Third
           on Third.Order_id=Second.Order_id inner join
           Fourth
           on Fourth.Order_id=Third.Order_id
     ) t1234
where seqnum = 1;
```

By the way, you could also express this using conditions in the `where` clause, because you appear to be using the joins only for filtering:

```
select count(First.Order_id) as [No.Of Orders], sum(First.Amount) as [Amount]
from First
where exists (select 1 from second where First.Order_id=Second.Order_id) and
      exists (select 1 from third where First.Order_id=third.Order_id) and
      exists (select 1 from fourth where First.Order_id=fourth.Order_id);
```

Comment: Thanks,your first query gives me error."The multi-part identifier "First.Order_id" could not be bound".